# How to share R environments between networked workstations

Tags: r, server, network-programming, client-server, rserve

We have multiple systems on the same network running R v3.3.2. In our individual systems, we are able to do all that we are required to do.

> Now our requirement is to make the system-2 access the vectors / lists
>   / dataframes created in system-1.
>
> In short, we need to connect together both the R workspaces residing
>   in two different systems but connected on the same network.

We are already aware of "Rserve" and "RSclient" packages but not sure how to proceed further.

Anybody can help me out on this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't need the platform that allows this to be written in R (ugh), how about: "How to share R environments between networked workstations."

Comment: Sorry @effel. I do not understand whether you are suggesting me to look into the question you have mentioned or are you asking me a question

Comment: I was suggesting a different title for your question.

Comment: @effel . Oh yes it looks better. Thank you. I will update the question title.

Comment: If you don't need simultaneous access from system1 and system2, you can save your workspace to a shared network drive/filesystem.

Comment: Hi @HongOoi . Unfortunately system1 and system2 needs to be used simultaneously. So the workspace cannot be kept in a shared network drive/filesystem